# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file php

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following error in the code below.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /admin/controller/module/megamenu.php on line 263 The list was updated
>   15-05-27 23:25:14!

**Line 263** : `foreach ($jsonArray as $subArray) {`

I checked on another server and does not appear this error (php5.4) but my server with php5.3, php5.5 appear. What's missing?

```
if (isset($_GET['jsonstring'])) {
        if($this->validate()){
            $jsonstring = $_GET['jsonstring'];
            $jsonDecoded = json_decode(html_entity_decode($jsonstring));

            function parseJsonArray($jsonArray, $parentID = 0) {
                $return = array();
                foreach ($jsonArray as $subArray) {
                    $returnSubSubArray = array();
                    if (isset($subArray->children)) {
                        $returnSubSubArray = parseJsonArray($subArray->children, $subArray->id);
                    }
                    $return[] = array('id' => $subArray->id, 'parentID' => $parentID);
                    $return = array_merge($return, $returnSubSubArray);
                }

                return $return;
            }


            $readbleArray = parseJsonArray($jsonDecoded);

            foreach ($readbleArray as $key => $value) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    $this->model_menu_megamenu->save_rang($value['parentID'], $value['id'], $key, $data['active_module_id']);
                }   
            }

            die("The list was updated ".date("y-m-d H:i:s")."!");

        } else {
            die($this->language->get('error_permission'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: why `html_entity_decode`?

Comment: As there is no `$jsonArray` before the function `parseJson()` is called I think there is your problem

Comment: Most likely the only difference between your different systems / php versions is the error reporting level. The behavior towards this issue should not be different at all.

Comment: Without the second argument set to `true` [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will return an *object*, not an array. It will also likely break if you keep using `html_entity_decode()` on the input, and embedding function declarations down in the middle of the logic is confusing *at best*.

Comment: `print_r($jsonArray)` and put the output here

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [children] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 11 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 12 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 13 ) ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [children] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 14 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 16 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 15 ) ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [children] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 17 ) ) ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 6 ) )

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$jsonDecoded = json_decode(html_entity_decode($jsonstring));
```

to

```
$jsonDecoded = json_decode(html_entity_decode($jsonstring),true);
```

and `$jsonDecoded` will be an array

Answer (score -1):

i think i some cases we have to use implode and explode functions when we work with json data in  php, try this after decoding your json data to convert an string to an array.